# Motivation for persistent homology with respect to eigenfunctions of distance kernel operator in a recent preprint

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, mg.metric-geometry, sp.spectral-theory, computational-topology, persistent-homology

I have a question about a recent preprint https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.02225.pdf by Maria, Oudot, and Solomon. As far as I understand, in Section 8 they prove that persistent homology (persistence diagrams, Betti numbers, Euler characteric) with respect to level sets of a function which is a linear combination of eigenfunctions of the distance kernel integral operator is well-behaved. The distance kernel operator $D^X$ is defined as $D^X(f)(x)=\int_X f(x) d(x,y) d\mu(y)$ where $d$ is the distance function on a compact metric measure space $(X, d, \mu)$.

My question is, why is one interested in persistent homology with respect to such functions (which are not explicit as they are eigenfunctions of some integral operator), as opposed to more explicit functions? Given this, why does one take the distance kernel operator instead of another integral operator (with a different kernel)? Are there other ways to construct functions suitable for taking level sets in the definition of persistent homology? These motivational questions don't seem to be mentioned in  the text of this preprint.

Is there any chance that one can actually calculate persistence diagrams, Betti numbers, Euler characteric with respect to the above eigenfunctions in terms of some underlying geometry (to have some explicit formulas for these topological invariants as opposed to just knowing that they exist/are well-behaved)?